# Converting keyboard input numbers into a numeric type

Tags: c#, asp.net

I m a bit stuck here. Though I know how to convert keyboard input character into usable character in C#.

```
char ch = (char)console.read();
```

I want to read numbers nd make them behave as numbers in my program.

If I enter 5 from keyboard I want to store as 5 (mathematical) not character 5.

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET question? You don't have a Console in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
int Number;
string strNumber;

strNumber = Console.ReadLine();
Number = int.Parse(strNumber);
```

Comment: Yes to be exact and to the point, This is what is answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

`int i = ch - '0';` ////.........

Comment: +1: Works great...for the usual decimal digits. I believe the Unicode category _Number, Decimal Digit_ includes rather more options than the usual 0-9: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm

Comment: This way works well, just make sure `ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'` before you try otherwise you'll get odd result.

Answer (score 1):

Safest way would be something like;

```
int Num = 0;

if( int.TryParse( ch.ToString(), out Num ) )
{
   // Num is now set correctly
}
else
{
   // ch didn't contain a digit.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Convert.ToInt32("5"), a safe alternative is Int32.TryParse() here are the docs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert_methods

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
string a = Console.ReadLine();
int b = int.Parse(a);
Console.WriteLine(b*b);
```